# Simple task with recursion on Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new in Prolog. So, I'm not sure if my code is ok and optimized. I'm also not sure if I use recursion correctly.

Task: find students that has at least 1 bad grade (1 or 2) and print them in table

```
hasBadGrades(N) :- student(_, N, G), containsBadGrades(G).

containsBadGrades([H|T]) :- wildcard_match('*/[1-2]', H); containsBadGrades(T).

printStudent(N, I) :- student(G, N, [M, C, O, P]),
   format("| ~a~t~5+ | ~a~t~5+ | ~a~t~16+ | ~a, ~a, ~a, ~a~t~41+ |~n", [I, G, N, M, C, O, P]).

printTHead :-
   printLine(),
   format("| ~a~t~5+ | ~a~t~5+ | ~a~t~16+ | ~a~t~40+ |~n", ['#', group, name, grades]),
   printLine().

printLine :- format("|~`-t~70||~n").

printList([S|T], N) :- printStudent(S, N), printLine(), K is N + 1, printList(T, K).

printFaildStudents :- printTHead(), setof(N, hasBadGrades(N), L), printList(L, 1).

student(1050, adams, ['math/4', 'c++/3', 'oop/4', 'physics/3']).
student(2100, alexander, ['math/3', 'c++/2', 'oop/4', 'physics/3']).
student(3151, allen, ['math/3', 'c++/4', 'oop/3', 'physics/3']).
student(4200, anderson, ['math/3', 'c++/2', 'oop/2', 'physics/3']).
student(5250, bailey, ['math/4', 'c++/3', 'oop/3', 'physics/4']).
student(1050, baker, ['math/3', 'c++/3', 'oop/4', 'physics/2']).
student(2100, barnes, ['math/4', 'c++/3', 'oop/3', 'physics/2']).
student(3151, bell, ['math/4', 'c++/3', 'oop/4', 'physics/4']).
student(4200, bennett, ['math/4', 'c++/3', 'oop/4', 'physics/3']).
student(5250, brooks, ['math/4', 'c++/3', 'oop/3', 'physics/3']).
student(1050, brown, ['math/3', 'c++/4', 'oop/4', 'physics/2']).
student(1050, flores, ['math/4', 'c++/3', 'oop/4', 'physics/3']).
student(2100, foster, ['math/4', 'c++/4', 'oop/3', 'physics/4']).
student(3151, garcia, ['math/3', 'c++/3', 'oop/2', 'physics/3']).
student(4200, gonzales, ['math/3', 'c++/4', 'oop/4', 'physics/3']).
student(5250, gonzalez, ['math/4', 'c++/2', 'oop/3', 'physics/3']).
student(1050, gray, ['math/3', 'c++/4', 'oop/3', 'physics/4']).
student(2100, green, ['math/2', 'c++/4', 'oop/1', 'physics/4']).
% . . .
```

[image]